Can you write a video file with out of order (input) frames?
I know video files can (and do) contain frames that are encoded out of order, which is why dts and pts exist, but can you send your frames in an arbitrary order, with their correct pts, and expect the video file to play?
Specifically I'm wondering about concatenating video files, can I decode both inputs in parallel and send the frames with the correct merged pts as they get decoded? And if so, what would the playback performance implications be?

I'm not sure what exactly are you trying to do? Concatenate how?

Since, as written, this doesn't appear to be about programming, you are more likely to get an answer (as suggested in the [tag:ffmpeg] tag help) on Video Production or Super User. Please make sure to search for existing similar questions and check their Help before posting, though. Thanks!

If you care whether the resulting video plays/decodes correctly, then no you can't write out of order, as Markus says.
But accurate encoding/decoding is not the only issue. Even if you used an intraframe-only compression frame format like MJPEG, players process and output decoded content in the order it's provided by the decoder. The decode order of each packet and presentation order don't always match, true, but in ffmpeg/libav for example, when you call avcodec_decode_video2 the context maintains its state as more packets are decoded; once there's enough data for full frames it gives them to you in the order you're supposed to play them back. It has no idea or concern for the possibility of frames way down the road that were supposed to be displayed earlier than the one it gives you.
After decode, the frames will go into a playback queue. At this point the player usually doesn't care about the absolute PTS; for video, it'll use the PTS difference between the current frame and the next frame solely to determine how long to hold the current frame. It's not able to look ahead any more than the decoder is - or if it does, certainly not that far - to see if there are frames coming with an earlier PTS. And for audio, it might ignore the PTS entirely once playback has begun and the video and audio are synced up - or if it does look at the PTS it'll solely be to handle a gap in the track. Either way, if a player later gets a PTS that's earlier than the current frame, I would expect it to either discard it, or else bug out from an integer overflow.
Remember most of these formats are designed for situations where random access is costly or impossible (i.e. optical or streaming). This is why proper interleaving between the video and audio is so important and most players will choke if the video stream gets even a little ahead of the audio or vice versa. That alone should tell you that no player would be able to handle video frames being dispersed out of order throughout the file.
FYI, the VLC media player's source demonstrates almost everything there is to know about video playback and ffmpeg/libav, and is a model to study if you want to know how players work.
If you're looking for a performance tip generally, you can and should encode each track in a separate thread with its own output queue, throttling one or the other if it gets too far ahead of the other, with a third write thread performing the interleave as it writes to disk. You can also do the inverse on the read side, for a total of 6 threads. But you still need to do this linearly with respect to each track; there is no way around this if you want it to play properly in any standard player.

I only have one track, so the performance tip at the end doesn't apply. "It has no idea or concern for the possibility of frames way down the road that were supposed to be displayed earlier than the one it gives you" makes a lot of sense though, thank you!

Incidentally, Firefox finally fixed Youtube VP9 playback, and the cause was that Youtube writes VP9 files with occasional out-of-order samples (like I was suggesting). So I guess that shows how common implementations handle this -- very poorly.

@Blindy multimedia in general is a complete $@%show. BTW, I was thinking, if the video files you're concatenating are all the same encoding parameters you shouldn't actually need to decode and re-encode at all. For videos after your first one, just add the appropriate offset to every AVPacket dts/pts/pos and write it back out. Also if you did this very carefully you could probably use the multithreading model you want - the packets from the later videos would just need to be written to the disk at the correct offsets. Tricky but doable.

Nah, in my case every frame requires additional processing (per-frame crop & scale). It's so complex that I had to modify my local ffmpeg build to allow what I'm trying to do.

Since we assume PTS and DTS can be different - I assume you want to deal with a format that contains B-Frames as part of an inter frame format like H.264 (AVC) or similar.
An inter frame format compresses the differences between frames rather than always the entire frame. So typically a P frame depends on previous frame(s) and B frames depend on previous and future frames. So you can't change the encode or transmission order. So it is not possible that you can encode multiple frames in parallel because you need the previously encoded frames to encode the current frame.
If you have a VOD (non live) scenario - you may be able to split you input into Group Of Frames (GOPs) and encode multiple GOPs in parallel.
Let's assume your GOP length (an encoder setting) is 10 and you want to run 3 parallel encodes.
Then you can encode frames 0-9, 10-19 and 20-29 in parallel and then recombine the chunks.

This is not about decoding, I'm asking if I can provide non-sequential frames to the encoder if I make sure their pts is in the correct order I want them to be seen in
